# what is a functioning query in sql developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to make a query for this below statement:
**find the ninth employee 9th highest salary**

I found below query from google

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e1
WHERE N-1 = 
           (SELECT COUNT(e2.ORIG_SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE e2
                  WHERE e2.ORIG_SALARY > e1.ORIG_SALARY)
in this query what is functioning role of " e1, e2 & N-1 "
```

please help to describe this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes in this query what is a functioning role of " e1, e2, & n-1"

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 1):

`e1,e2` are aliases . N is numerical others. In you case is `9`.

This query has a correlated subquery. For each row from table employee, it calculates the count of the employee with the higher salary. Why ( N-1 , 9-1= 8) because If you find 8 employees with the higher salary. Probably current row has 9th salary.

But for me, this solution is not clear. 
I prefer analytic function for this.

```
Select * from (
SELECT e1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY e1.sal) rn  FROM emp e1) where rn =9;



Select * from (
SELECT e1.*, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY e1.sal) rn  FROM emp e1) where rn = 9;
```